# (issue) redirect route cakephp

Tags: cakephp, redirect, routes

sorry, my English so bad.

In CakePHP 2.x, I want to redirect old link to new link in my website. But i got some issue.

Example:

mywebsite.com/news/news redirect to mywebsite.com/news
I use:

```
 Router::redirect ('/news/news',
    array('controller' => 'categories', 
        'action' => 'index', 
        'slug' => 'news'
    ),
    array(
        'status' => '301'
    )
);
Router::connect('/news', array(
    'controller' => 'categories', 
    'action' => 'index', 
    'slug' => 'news'
));
```

=> OK, it work.

But

Example:
mywebsite.com/news/news/a-b-c redirect to mywebsite.com/news/a-b-c

I use:

```
    Router::redirect('/news/news/:slug',
    array(
        'controller' => 'articles',
        'action' => 'view',
        'category' => 'news'
    ),
    array(
        'status' => '301'
    )
);

Router::connect('/news/:slug',
    array(
        'controller' => 'articles',
        'action' => 'view',
        'category' => 'news'
    )
);
```

=> result is: mywebsite.com/articles/view/category:news

Please help, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting all requests from `news/news/*` to `articles/view/category:*`

Do you need the 301 redirect in there at all?

```
  Router::connect('/news/news/:slug',
    array(
        'controller' => 'news',
        'action' => 'slug'
    )
);
```

But on this basis, the controller will expect a defined action for every type of `a-b-c` action that can be passed as a slug

Comment: a-b-c is slug. I need redirect to /news/:slug :)